# Regex / Preg: No match, if found

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, bbcode

I'm trying to do some PHP preg. But it seems to i can't get it to match if i want a string without something in it.

Example:

```
Hello! My name is [b]Peter Jack[/b]
```

If Peter Jack is found with his last name, it will NOT match, but if its found "[b]Peter[/b]" it will match.

Anyone who I'm kinda bad at explaining things, comment if there is anything else you need to help me solve this.

---

Another way I can say it about, is, if i got a link to a website, it will match and do the stuff in the preg_replace, but if the link to the website ends with like .png (an image) it will not match and will not make a link.

```
example.com/image.png
```

Will not be matched because it contains .png

```
example.com/image
```

Will be matched because it does **not** contain .png

Comment: Could you add your code to the question?

Comment: What's your current regex? You should be able to match it with `/\[b\](.*)\[\/b\]/`?

Comment: Why did you construct a misleading example when your actual question was much easier to understand, and also much more specific? Please show some actual examples of strings you do and don't want to match.

Comment: I thought it was easier if i told it about a word, instead of some image tags on some links...

Comment: With regexes you have to be very specific. Simplifying examples is almost always a bad idea. You need to have a very good understanding of the rules for matches/non-matches; otherwise you (or we) won't be able to construct a regex that works correctly for your purposes.

Comment: Are the links already surrounded by tags, or do they occur in plain text?

Comment: OK, so how can you tell what's a link and what isn't? By the way, since this is a completely different question from what you had asked in the beginning, you might want to make this a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear what you want to find. If it's just `[b]Peter[/b]`, then you don't need a regex.

If you want to find a single "word" surrounded by BBCode bold tags, use

```
preg_match('%\[b\]\w*\[/b\]%', $subject)
```

If you want to find anything within BBCode bold tags as long as it doesn't contain `Jack`, use

```
preg_match(
    '%\[b\]     # Match [b]
    (?:         # Try to match...
     (?!Jack)   # (unless the word "Jack" occurs there)
     .          # any character
    )*?         # any number of times, as few as possible
    \[/b\]      # Match [/b]%x', 
    $subject)
```

Comment: No, its mostly for tags, ect. I only want it to find the matches if a word is NOT in it.

Comment: Note: its for preg_replace so i am enable to replace if its NOT there, notice some more information i added to the question at the bottom of it.