# Match text if it doesn't contain a certain substring

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regex / Preg: No match, if found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12447818/regex-preg-no-match-if-found)

I want to use `preg_replace` to replace some string if something in the string is NOT there. That is, if the substring is there, the string won't be matched.

For example, if the string contains `.png`, it won't find/match it.

```
example.com/image.png
```

Here, it will not find it because the string contains the line/substring `.png`.

```
example.com/image
```

Here, it will find it, because the string does **not** contain the line/substring `.png` anywhere.

---

For those who still does not get me.

```
$result = preg_replace("#http://(.*\S)[Something here that will not match the link if it finds the .png at last]#","<a href='\\1'>\\1</a>","Here is a link that should work http://example.com/; Here is a link that should NOT work http://example.com/image.png")
```

Comment: Is `example.com/image` the entire string, or just part of the string? If it's just part of the string… what's the criteria for finding it?

Comment: Like, if it was a post: "Hello, check this out! http://example.com/image" it will find the link and make it a link with preg_replace, but if its like this: "Hello, check this out! http://example.com/image.png" it will just not do anything with it...

Comment: So you want to match URLs? Do you already have a regular expression for doing that?

Comment: OK, you and I know (gut feeling) that `example.com/image` is supposed to be a URL, and `check` probably isn't. But how are you going to teach the computer that? What makes a substring a link? After all, that "link" isn't a valid URL.

Comment: Ad you might don't get, the php code will find out that itself with the pregs, but i still need help to leave it if it finds something else that in this case, if it find the .png in the link/substring it will not match it.

Comment: Still hard to understand what you want... So you want a regex that excludes only the string `.png`?

Comment: For the love of... its quite simple. All i wanted it so have a code make a link ONLY if the .png is NOT found. - using preg_replace - PHP

Comment: @Kevin, the problem is if the post is, say, "Hello, world!". Then it will not match `.png`. What will happen then? Do you already have logic for this, or is catching this case a part of the question?

Comment: It's not that simple. First you need to define how to find a URL in plain text. This, as regex guru Jan Goyvaerts [posted in his blog](http://www.regexguru.com/2008/11/detecting-urls-in-a-block-of-text/), is already nearly impossible to do. Once you have that, you can filter out matches that end in `.png`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I'm going out on a limb here.

First, you need a regex that'll find a URL for you. Since you apparently want to find lots of invalid URLs, too, we'll take a regex that simply considers any string of consecutive non-space character that contains a sequence `<letter>.<letter>`:

```
\b(?=\S*[a-z]\.[a-z])\S+(?=\s|$)
```

Then we can check that this sequence doesn't end in `.png`:

```
\b(?=\S*[a-z]\.[a-z])\S+(?=\s|$)(?<!\.png)
```

Now you can use that for a replace operation, for example

```
$result = preg_replace(
    '/\b           # Start at a word boundary
    (?=            # Assert that it\'s possible to match...
     \S*           # any number of non-whitespace characters
     [a-z]\.[a-z]  # followed by an ASCII letter, a dot, a letter
    )              # End of lookahead assertion
    \S+            # Match one or more non-whitespace characters
    (?=\s|$)       # until the next whitespace or end of string
    (?<!\.png)     # unless that match ends in .png/ix', 
    '<a href="\0">\0</a>', $subject);
```

Comment: Well, for some reason, it will not work with ?<! or ?!

Comment: I've tested on my local version of php 5.3.6 and it seems to work for me... which version did you use (the inline or the one with the comments)? `preg_replace('#\b(?=\S*[a-z]\.[a-z])\S+(?=\s|$)(?<!\.png)#i', '<a href="\0">\0</a>', $text);` is working fine for me...

Comment: @do0l67: You really need to learn to be more specific. What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? How exactly did you use the regex?

Answer (score 0):

This would be how I would approach the problem, it's rather tricky to get a "not" RegExp working - as it isn't really what the system was designed for. So instead seperate the logic up so that you have two RegExps... one searching for the link-like structure and then one checking for the cases you want to avoid:

```
function replaceWithLink ( $find ) {
  list($link) = $find;
  if ( preg_match('/\.(png|gif|image)$/', $link) ) {
    return $link;
  }
  else {
    return '<a href="'.$link.'">'.$link.'</a>';
  }
}

$text = 'This is my test string that contains a url.like/thing but '.
        'it also contains another url.like/thing/that-has-an.image '.
        'should they all be highlighted?';

$expr = '#[a-z0-9:_\-\.]+/[a-z0-9_\-\./]+#i';
$func = 'replaceWithLink';

$text = preg_replace_callback($expr, $func, $text);
```

The above is more readable than having one overly complicated RegExp, and is easily extendable to handle more extensions. Obviously in order to get this to work properly with URLs you may need to tweak the RegExp that is searching for them - I've just thrown one together rather quickly. In my version the URLs have to contain `URL-like text`, followed by `/`, followed by `URL-like text possibly with slash` in order to qualify.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$yourInputString = 'whatever';
$matchPattern = '/^.*?(?<!\.png)$/i';
$replacePattern = '$0.png';
$result = preg_replace($matchPattern, $replacePattern, $yourInputString);
```

Note that your input string will need to contain only the link you are processing, e.g.:

```
example.com/image.png
```

or

```
example.com/image
```

Here's the explanation of the pattern:

```
# ^.*?(?<!\.png)$
# 
# Options: case insensitive
# 
# Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character) «^»
# Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*?»
#    Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
# Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below with the match ending at this position (negative lookbehind) «(?<!\.png)»
#    Match the character “.” literally «\.»
#    Match the characters “png” literally «png»
# Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character) «$»
```